# Installing Firebase CLI using npm

Tags: flutter, npm, nvm, firebase-tools

I installed `NVM for Windows` using this tool `https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows`.

```
>nvm --version
1.1.11
```

Firebase CLI reference says that `Installing Node.js automatically installs the npm command tools.`
Nevertheless, when I try to install the Firebase CLI using the following command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

the `npm` command is not found

Does it require to setup some additional environment variables to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm (Node version manager) manages different versions of node. And node contains npm (node package manager) So you need to install node inorder to use npm.

You can download node here:

https://nodejs.org/en/download